# Use #define to specify multiple paramaters

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I would like to use a #define to specify multiple parameters for another #define. Is this possible? The following code gives an error that OUTPUT_HIGH requires 2 inputs.

```
#define OUTPUT_HIGH(port, pin) port |= (1 << pin)
#define LED0 PORTB, PINB2

main() {
    OUTPUT_HIGH(LED0); //Invalid
    OUTPUT_HIGH(PORTB, PINB2); //Valid
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: My goal is to abstract away implementation details.

Comment: They are #defines related to my microcontroller. I don't think it makes a difference to the answer?

Comment: That means PORTB and PINB2 are also #define? It may or it may not be. I am asking for clarification though...

Comment: I think so. A solution which works for `#define LED0 1, 2` should work the same way.

Comment: At the very least, the `PORTB` cannot be a `#define` I think... since it is assigned to something, it should be a variable.

Comment: Sorry, what am I thinking, PORTB is a register (so, a uint8_t).